# Does KDB have a ruby binding?

Tags: ruby

The number of language bindings for KDB seems to be very limited. My projects use ruby, php and lua in good measure and I am not sure if KDB bindings are available for all of them. Specifically, I need ruby and kdb talking to each other soon and looking out for options.

Comment: I'm writing one. Please contribute ! --> https://github.com/amangupta052/ruby-kdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about ruby but i faced the same issue with php, i resolved it using the http call functionality of kdb

```
htttp://server:port?select from table
```